# Content based filtering-selector string-IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I have created a Topic and a subscription to it which has a selector string('Target=''sub''').I am trying to publish a message from RFHUtil by
 passing **Taget=sub** in usr tab and  **Include RFH V2 header** option is checked as well.
But it's failing with Error **cc=2 rc=2551 Cannot Put**.
Any suggestions please.[image: Topic]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After recreating:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect when creating your subscription in MQ Explorer (first screenshot) you don't need the single quotes, and your selector entry field should just contain Target="sub". When adding the property using RFHUtil, I would expect your Usr folder contents need to be Target="sub", that is you need the double quotes?

Comment: Thanks for responding.I created subscription selector string Target="sub"(double quotes) and passed Target="sub"(double quotes) in RFHUtil.It says message has been published but the status count on subscription is 0.
I tried the other way by creating subscription selector string with 2 single quotes(Target=''sub'').Got 2551 error for this.

Comment: The Selector property is using the SQL92 query syntax and uses single quotes to represent a string. Target='sub' should be the correct value for the selector string.

Comment: I tried with selector string Target='sub' and passing the same from RHFUtil usr tab but no luck. RFHUtil status shows as published but the count on subscription is 0 and no message on Q.

Comment: Break it down into two separate steps. Use the sample amqsstma to put a message with a string selector and check that your application can read it. Use the sample amqsiqma to see if it can read the string selector that you are putting with RFHUtil. Then add the subscription in, first with no selector, and check that you can read the property, then with the full selector. Find out which part isn't working as it should. After further research, I agree with above recommendation that single quotes is what is need around string value - apologies for earlier mi-information.